# Dynamic headers per request with Feign requestInterceptor?

Tags: java, rest, netflix-feign, feign

I am using Feign to make my http call. For security reason, I need to generate and add header on each request.
Headers values may differ on each request (for example, it use current connected user in session).
With Feign we can define a requestInterceptor to handle header generation.
But my problem, I that a requestInterceptor is defined when FeignBuilder is used. But after building my client, I can't access easily to this interceptor (except keep a reference on it). 
Ex:

```
MyApi api = Feign.builder()
.requestInterceptor(new SecuringRequestInterceptor("some static value"))
.target(MyApi.class, "http://....");
```

How can I add some per request specific value to this interceptor to let it generate some kind of header based on these values ?
I have try to keep a reference on the requestInterceptor instance and create a method to update his status. But I don't think it is thread safe in a concurrent environment :

```
class SecuringRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    private String staticValue;
    private String dynamicValue;
    public SecuringRequestInterceptor(String value) {
        this.staticValue = value;
    }
    public void update(String value) {
        this.dynamicValue = dynamicValue;
    }
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        // use dynamic value here
        template.header("sign", this.staticValue + "_" + this.dynamicValue);
    } 
}
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: You use sprig? If true you can make `SecuringRequestInterceptor` as bean with session scope and store dynamic data to session.

Comment: no I am using as standalone lib (standard Java EE 5 app)

Comment: Ok, you can use `@RequestHeader` annotation for feign client, create wrapper service for client and in wrapper service get and set dynamic value in client. It may be look like `interface MyApiService -> class MyApiServiceImpl -> interface MyApi`

Comment: Ok, but how did you change/set headers from the wrapper ?